# Download specific FTP files using SSIS Foreach Loop Container and database table filenames

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

FTP server folder: CIV.2-130211067212254633
Filenames to be created by concatenating the folder name with values from a SQL Server database column
I have an FTP server connection manager configured in my SSIS package
What I'm trying to achieve using SSIS:
folder inside (CIV.2-130211067212254633) values are available, this values are available in database table
Retrieve values from a specific column in a SQL Server database table.
Concatenate these values with the fixed folder name CIV.2-130211067212254633.
Use the concatenated filenames to download corresponding files from the FTP server to a local directory.
I'm aware of the FTP Task and Foreach Loop Container in SSIS, but I'm not sure about the exact steps needed to dynamically generate the concatenated filenames and complete the download process without using a Script Task. I'd greatly appreciate any guidance, examples, or step-by-step instructions on how to achieve this.

Thank you for your time and assistance!

For example
CIV.2-130211067212254633 this folder is existing in my ftp server
in this folder 201209128049024171150137181089063136029222080012.Upload
201209128049024171150137181089063136029222080012.Upload
227185120237186243054143088186044183069216181077.Upload
these file names are available,, this file names are already stored in data base table in one column.
based on this files will be downloading into local like
CIV.2-130211067212254633 201209128049024171150137181089063136029222080012.Upload
CIV.2-130211067212254633 227185120237186243054143088186044183069216181077.Upload
we want without script task.